# Would someone be able to give me a basic understanding of s(x1), s(x2), s(x3), etc. terms work in R Generalized Additive Models (GAM)?

Tags: r, generalized-additive-model, mgcv

Hi there would someone be able to explain to me how the `s(x1)` terms work in the GAMS?

For instance in the equation:

```r
gam(response ~ s(x1) + s(x2) + s(x3))
```

Would each smoother variable be “accounting for the influence on each other and on the response” after than `gam` was ran? In other words, would the graph produced between the response variable and `x1` also account for the influence of `x2` and `x3` on the response? If not, if there a way to account for this interaction?

In addition to this, I'm wondering if this was a built model for one dataset could it be used on a different dataset to predict and generate values for the response variable of interest if I had data for `x1`, `x2`, and `x3`?

I'm admittedly a beginner to GAMs in R so I'm having a hard time even knowing that vocab to find out how to understand this problem. I really appreciate any advice or insight anyone has.

Comment: These are very basic questions which are answered by basic documentation and tutorials. GAM stands for "generalized additive model", note the "additive" part. That means your example doesn't model interactions. However, mgcv provides interaction smoothers, see `help("te")`. Study `help("predict.gam")` to learn how to predict from the model with new data.

Answer (score 1):

I provided the following answer to exactly the same questions sent to me directly by email. I hadn't noticed that this had been asked on [so] or here before replying privately.

GAMs work just like other regression models, they just don't enforce a particular parametric relationship between covariates and the response.

The model

```r
gam(y ~ s(x1) + s(x2) + s(x3)
```

estimates smooth effects of `x1` conditional upon the smooth effects of the two other covariates, and vice versa. But then you mention "interaction" so I wonder if you mean is the effect of `x1` allowed to vary with either one or both of the other covariates' effects? If so, no; this model is an **additive** model.

If you want the equivalent of an interaction but for smooths, you would need to fit

```r
gam(y ~ te(x1, x2, x3))
```

but you'd need a lot of data to estimate a 3D smooth like this because of the curse of dimensionality.

You can use GAM for prediction; mgcv has a `predict()` method where you can supply new values of the covariates. Just be careful not to predict outside the observed range of your covariates unless you know what you are doing and what the implications are.